# Cloudflare security level is not changing from api

Tags: php, curl, cloudflare

I am trying to change the security_level from curl for cloudflare api

```
$ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/zoneId/setings/security_level");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, array('X-Auth-Email'=>'Email','X-Auth-Key'=>'Api_key','Content-Type'=>'application/json'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('value' => 'MEDIUM'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
```

But i am getting error as given below:

> {"success":false,"errors":[{"code":7003,"message":"Could not route to /zones/zoneId/settings/security_level, perhaps your object identifier is invalid?"},{"code":7000,"message":"No route for that URI"}],"messages":[],"result":null}

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when I tried to change security level through api. I was wondering how GET gives me correct result and PATCH command fails.

For example:

```
curl -v -X GET https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/my_zone_id/settings/security_level \
-H "X-Auth-Email: my_email" \
-H "Content-Type:application/json" \
-H "X-Auth-Key: my_Global_API_Key" | jq
```

was giving me:

```
{
  "result": {
    "id": "security_level",
    "value": "high",
    "modified_on": "2019-02-07T17:05:58.073422Z",
    "editable": true
  },
  "success": true,
  "errors": [],
  "messages": []
}
```

but:

```
curl -X PATCH "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/my_zone_id/settings/security_level" \ 
-H "X-Auth-Email: my_email" \
-H "Content-Type:application/json" \
-H "X-Auth-Key: my_Global_API_Key" \
--data '{"value":"under_attack"}'
```

was giving me:

```
{"success":false,"errors":[{"code":7003,"message":"Could not route to \/zones\/my_zone_id\/settings\/security_level, perhaps your object identifier is invalid?"},{"code":7000,"message":"No route for that URI"
```

Somehow I realized that the issue was in copy/paste. When I re-enter the PATCH command again, everything worked.